# is $f_n=x^{-n} $convergent point wise? uniformly?

Tags: uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I believe on [1,2] $$f_n=x^{-n} $$
is point wise convergent because in n tends to infinity, there can be a function like f=0, such that $$|f_n-f|$$ tends to zero. hence this function is point wise convergent and it converges to 0; am I right?
secondly, it is not uniformly convergent because when n tends to infinity ,
$$||f_n-f||_{\infty}$$
does not tend to zero.
am I correct. I am not sure about my explanations.

Answer (score 1):

At the point $x=1$ it actually converges to $1$. At any other point it converges to $0$. Hence the limit function is not continuous, so the convergence cannot be uniform. (uniform limit of continuous functions must be continuous)

Comment: thanks. so Do you mean because f converges to two numbers 1 and zero, it is not point wise convergent either?

Comment: It is pointwise convergent. For every constant $x\in [1,2]$ you have a convergent sequence. So by definition it converges pointwise. The limit function $f$ satisfies $f(1)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in (1,2]$. Since all the functions in the sequence are continuous but the limit function isn't we conclude that the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand :-)